# How to list every image for the object with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I want to show every image I that the user upload on the Show page. Reading the documentation and watching some videos I was able to create the uploader and make it work. (maybe it is obvious, but for me was very big deal). I look to the Gem documentation but didn't find this specific. I try to do some each to the object but didn't work. 

This is my model

```
class Imovel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bairro
  belongs_to :tipoimovel
  has_many :caracteristica_imovels, inverse_of: :imovel
    has_many :caracteristicas, through: :caracteristica_imovels, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :caracteristica_imovels, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  mount_uploaders :imagens, ImagemUploader
end
```

This is the uploader code:

```
class ImagemUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

This is my _form and how it uploads

```
<%= f.file_field :imagens, multiple: true, class: "float-left" %>
```

I the show page I am displaying by this:

```
 <%= image_tag(@imovel.imagens[1].url) if @imovel.imagens? %>
```

Here is the problem, I have the array index, and I don't know how I can make it work dynamical.
How can I do this?

Comment: Just loop though it with `@imovel.imagens.each do ...`

Comment: Also limit yourself to a single question. Not two unrelated questions.

Comment: Already try to do this but throws a error: undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass. Try like this: <% @imovel.imagens.each do |imagem| %>
        <%= image_tag(@imagem.url) if @imovel.imagens? %>
      <% end %> what did I miss? Sorry about the two questions, already make it right, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thank you very much, I try a little more and you're right. It works with this: <% @imovel.imagens.each do |imagem| %>
        <%= image_tag(imagem.url) if @imovel.imagens? %>
      <% end %>

Comment: You can remove ` if @imovel.imagens?` as the block won't be called if the collection is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the tips you solve my problem, do you want to answer for me to accept and thumbs up?

Comment: You can answer the question yourself. I don't really need rep.

Comment: I just did that, thanks again. Respect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @max the right way to do it it's with the each method, doing properly. Code is bellow:

```
<% @imovel.imagens.each do |imagem| %> 
     <%= image_tag(imagem.url) %>
<% end %>
```